# How to slightly modify a variable function in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So we have something like this:

```
var variable1 = 1;
var variable2 = 2;

var doSomething = function() {
    alert(variable1 + ' ' + variable2);
}; // After this initialization, the content of that variable is completely hidden from the programmer's eyes.

doSomething(); // 1 2

// How to modify doSomething to update **`variable2`** to 3?

doSomething(); // ...Would like to modify doSomething to be able to output 1 3
```

Is it possible to take **`doSomething`** and update its `variable2` portion to a new value?

If we need to re-create the function within **`doSomething`** variable, it must come from the information stored in **`doSomething`** and not hard coded.

Comment: Functions cannot be altered after they're created. However, in your sample code you can simply set `variable2 = 3` any time you want.

Comment: Can you make `variable2` an argument?

Comment: @Pointy Bad idea. Avoid global variables.

Comment: I know you posted the bare minimum as an example. So, can you just duplicate the functionality of `doSomething()` with a different function name, and just run your own version ignoring the original?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon well they're not *my* global variables :)  Plus for all we know this code is inside another function.

Answer (score 0):

neet to set variable2 = 3 before function call

```js
var variable1 = 1;
var variable2 = 2;

var doSomething = function() {
    alert(variable1 + ' ' + variable2);
}; // After this initialization, the content of that variable is completely hidden from the programmer's eyes.

doSomething(); // 1 2

//set variable2 = 3 

variable2 =3;

doSomething(); // ...Would like to modify doSomething to be able to output 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable2 an [optional parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20function%20parameters%20default,set%20a%20different%20default%20value.&text=In%20the%20past%2C%20the%20general,value%20if%20they%20are%20undefined%20.):

```
var variable1 = 1;
var variable2 = 2;

var doSomething = function(v2 = variable2) {
    alert(variable1 + ' ' + v2);
};

doSomething(3);
```